# Run sql query x times

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to run the sql query for x times ? For example I want to generate and insert X codes in my table.. The way I use at the moment is;

```
$code1 = generateCode();
$code2 = generateCode();
$insert1 = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `codes` VALUES (NULL, :code)");
```

$insert1 -> execute(array(':code' => $code1));
    $insert1 = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `codes` VALUES (NULL, :code)");
$insert1 -> execute(array(':code' => $code2));

Comment: You could write one insert statement in a loop. ave you tried that?

Comment: If you're running the same query multiple times, then you don't have to prepare it every single time (that's one of the big benefits of prepared statements)... prepare it once, then just execute it multiple times with the different code values

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a loop in php . . . which might be the easiest way.  Another way is to use a subquery to get the rows you want:

```
INSERT INTO `codes` 
    select NULL, :code
    from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) t;
```

If you know you have a table with enough rows, you can just do:

```
INSERT INTO `codes` 
    select NULL, :code
    from table t
    limit 3;
```

Note:  when using `insert` you should almost always include the columns after the table name.

Comment: Alright let's say that I have used a loop to generate and insert into table 50 codes like this; for ($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++)
{
 $insert = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `codes` VALUES (NULL, :coupon)");
 $insert -> execute(array(':coupon' => couponCode()));
} , how do I get the output of generated codes each in one line ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it 50 times,

```
$codes = [];
$insert1 = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `codes` VALUES (NULL, :code)");
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; ++$i) {
    $code = generateCode();
    $insert1 -> execute(array(':code' => $code));
    $codes[] = $code;
}
echo implode(', ', $codes);
```